# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'JO_Exception' with message 'exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]

Tags: mysql, pdo, paypal

After researching the related topics on this problem, as well as checking to be sure PDO drivers for MySql were enabled in phpinfo.php, I need more insight. Here's the error messages:

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'JO_Exception' with message 'exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'bebopshop.paypal_permission' doesn't exist' in /var/www/vhosts/thedomain.com/bebopshop/httpdocs/JO/v.1.0a/JO/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228 

    Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/thedomain.com/bebopshop/httpdocs/JO/v.1.0a/JO/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /var/www/vhosts/thedomain.com/bebopshop/httpdocs/JO/v.1.0a/JO/Db/Statement.php(300): JO_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) #2 /var/www/vhosts/thedomain.com/bebopshop/httpdocs/JO/v.1.0a/JO/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(473): 

    JO_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #3 /var/www/vhosts/thedomain.com/bebopshop/httpdocs/JO/v.1.0a/JO/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): JO_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query(Object(JO_Db_Select), Array) #4 /var/www/vhosts/thedomain.com/bebopshop/httpdocs/JO/v.1.0a/JO/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(779):

    JO_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query(Object(JO_Db_Select), Array) #5 /var/www/vhosts/thedomain in /var/www/vhosts/thedomain.com/bebopshop/httpdocs/JO/v.1.0a/JO/Application.php on line 547
```

Since this is related to PayPal, I checked the folders:
adaptivepayments-sdk-php
merchant-sdk-php
permissions-sdk-php
sdk-core-php

All of the config files have the required credentials. I am at a dead end: What am I missing? All help would be appreciated to resolve this problem.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You appear to be querying your database `bebopshop` for a table `paypal_permission` that doesn't exist...

Comment: Read the error message: _Table 'bebopshop.paypal_permission' doesn't exist'_. This could be a clue.

Comment: Yep, exactly right-problem is that from the stack trace, I have no clue about creating the table parameters. Any ideas on this?